# Cucumber DataTable with two different classes

Tags: java, datatable, cucumber, bdd

I'm using cucumber for BDD and in one feature have this type of datatable, how can I differentiate in cucumber generated method which class should be used

```
And the following set of "Toys"
    | name           |something1| 
    | plane          |  400     |  
    | ball           |  800     |  
 And the following set of "Shoes"
    | name           | something2| 
    | boots          |   35      | 
    | sandals        |   35      |
```

This implementation throws exception Can't convert a table to java.util.List. When using List, SomeComplexType must not be a generic type

```
@Given("^the following set of \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public <T> void the_following_set_of(String type, List<T> info) throws Throwable {
    switch (type) {
    case "Toys":            

        break;
    case "Shoes":
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to get automatic conversion to a list of typed objects if the type is also a parameter because Cucumber will not know which type it should be converting to when it calls the definition. You would have to use the code you have above and do your conversion manually. Cucumber will do the conversion for you if you have a method per type though, e.g.:

```
@When("^the following set of toys")
public void the_following_set_of(List<Toy> toys) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(toys);
}
// ... another method for shoes, etc.
```

Then, just define a simple bean for toy with the same property names you are using in your table headers so Cucumber knows which fields to populate:

```
public class Toy {
    private String name;
    private String something1;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    // ... etc.
}
```

Cucumber should now call your method with a populated list of Toy's for the clause "And the following set of toys".